# In Power BI, how to display a graph of the count for values in a column

Tags: report, dax, measure

I have a table with columns CaseID, BidDate, DateOffered, DaysToBid.
DaysToBid is calculated, and is just the difference between the DateOffered and the BidDate.  There are multiple bids for each Case, one bid per line.

I want to show a graph with x-axis = number of days (from 0 to 365, say), and the cumulative number (i.e., count) of bids where the DaysToBid is <= x value.
I also need to filter the graph by the DateOffered field, showing, e.g., data for a given month, or quarter or year.

I've been working on this for days, and can't figure out how to do it.  I had built a table with a column of numbers (days) to serve as the x values, and a calculated column with the cumulative number of bids. I just realized that the reason the date range filter wasn't working is that calculated columns aren't dynamic, so that approach was hopeless--a rookie mistake.  The data I did get was for every bid in the file, not in a date range.  I was using harvested measure for [MinDate] and [MaxDate] from the Calendar table.

Just how do I set this up?  It seems like a common enough situation, but I couldn't find any suggestions online as to how to create this.

The failed calculated column in the Numbers table was as follows. But obviously this never gets to a filter context in the Report, so [MinDate] and [MaxDate] reference the entire calendar, not a =selected range.

```
Cumul_Bids = CALCULATE(
                COUNT('Buyer_Review'[DaysToBid]), 
                FILTER('Buyer_Review', 
                    [DaysToBid] <= Numbers[Number of Days]
                    && [BidDate] >= [MinDate] 
                    && [BidDate] <= [MaxDate]
                )
            )
```

Comment: Can you clarify why the following simple `measure` (not calculated column) does not work for you? `Cumul_Bids = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Buyer_Review),Buyer_Review[DaysToBid]<=MAX(Numbers[Number of Days]))` Used as Values in a chart visual with Number of Days on the Axis.

Comment: D'Oh!  Yes, that works perfectly.  Using =MAX(Numbers[Number of Days]) still seems counter-intuitive to me, which is why using that didn't occur to me.  Figuring out how to hook into the Number of Days column from the measure was what eluded me.

Thanks--you've made my day!

Comment: It never fails--when I have a problem, the solution always involves simplifying, not adding complexity!